# Why is FileWriter not writing to "output.csv" but does write to the exact path "C:\\path\\output.csv"?

Tags: java, file, filewriter

There are no errors thrown. It will work if I specify the exact path but not if I just say "output.csv"

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from geninfo");
                try {
                    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File("output.csv")));
                    writer.writeAll(rs, true);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SQLite.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

Comment: Where is the output.csv file located with relations to the class file?

Comment: Without specifying the root path, it could be trying to write to the JAVA_HOME directory, which you may not have permissions for. Could that be the case?

Comment: @Tdorno It is in the project folder along with my build and source folder

Comment: I suggest you use try-with-resources, or close the writer in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just say output.csv it should write to the working directory, which is usually the directory you started Java from, but that can vary depending on if you're starting from an IDE.

You can check the actual file it's using though with:

```
new File("output.csv").getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Interesting, it was being created in my tomcat server's bin folder. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution: this executes a query then sends the result sets to a output csv file.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;    
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class TableExport {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","name","password");
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultData = statement.executeQuery("select * from your_table");

                CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File("D:/Uploads/Output5.csv")), '|');
                writer.writeAll(resultData, true);
                writer.close();

}catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error" +e);
   }

  }
}
```

please give me comments if you like this code or it helps your purpose.....